# When I click on an input in the first grid element, all forms text altered; how can I stop this? (Clicking any other item's inputs doesn't cause this)

Tags: html, css, forms, input, css-grid

Here is the page upon loading in:
[image]

Observe when we click an input in the first grid item:
(ok i was gonna show it properly but it only happens when you have clicked on an input and nothing
else, trying anything to take a screenshot de-selects the input so its difficult to show)
[image]

^What pretty much happens tho is that all of the pink text (only the text, no not the borders, yes even the button texts) you see on screen becomes mildly dimmer (as though either its font had downsized or the text colors brightness decreased).

Observe that this doesn't happen when we click on the inputs in the other grid item:
[image]

The screenshot thing is kinda making writing this feel pointless, I thought I should at least give it a shot since I've just been stuck on this for a while now. Does anyone know what's going on or have any advice that might help? First time posting here, go easy on me.

HTML:

```
<div id = "formscontainer">
            
        <div id = "logincontainer">
            <div class = "dashbar">Log In</div>

            <form id = "loginform">
                <div id = "userwrap">
                    <input id = "loginuser" type = "text">
                </div>
                <div id = "passwrap">
                    <input id = "loginpass" type = "text">
                </div>

                <button id = "loginbutton" type = "submit">Login</button>
                <button id = "recoverbutton" type = "submit">Recover</button>
            </form>

            <p>
                For best user experience, please enable cookies in your browser. This is simply to ensure that you don't have to 
                log in consecutively in the same window. The service will automatically be able to identify your session when cookies 
                are enabled and you have logged in successfully without logging back out. Please be safe and enjoy!
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id = "signupcontainer">
            <div class = "dashbar">Create an Account</div>

            <form id = "createform">
                <div id = "userwrapW">
                    <input id = "createuser" type = "text">
                </div>
                <div id = "passwrapW">
                    <input id = "createpass" type = "text">
                </div>
                <div id = "reenterwrapW">
                    <input id = "createreenter" type = "text">
                </div>

                <button id = "createbutton" type = "submit">Create</button>
                <button id = "aboutbutton" type = "submit">About</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono&display=swap');

body
{
    background:black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
}
```

```
#formscontainer
{
    width: 70vw;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 17%;
    z-index: 9;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25vw 40vw;
    grid-template-rows: 73vh;
    grid-gap: 2vw;
}

#logincontainer
{   
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #0d0d0d, #171717);
}

#signupcontainer
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #0d0d0d, #171717);
}

.dashbar
{
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.dashbar::after
{
    content: "";
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0% 3%, #FF008B 3% 98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 98%);;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
}

#loginform input
{
    background-color: /*#2e2b2b*/#1d1d1d;
    font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-left: 0.85vw;
    color: white;
    width: 23.1vw;
    height: 3vh;
    margin-top: 9vh;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#createform input
{
    background-color: /*#2e2b2b*/#1d1d1d;
    font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-left: 0.85vw;
    color: white;
    width: 38.1vw;
    height: 3vh;
    margin-top: 9vh;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#userwrap::before
{
    content: "Username:";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #FF008B;
    width: 3.56vw;
    height: 1vh;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.5vh;
    left: 1vw;
}
    
#userwrap::after
{
    content: "";
    background-color: #FF008B;
    width: 23.28vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0.85vw;
    height: 0.1vh;
    display: block;
}
    
#passwrap::before
{
    content: "Password:";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #FF008B;
    width: 3.56vw;
    height: 1vh;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.5vh;
    left: 1vw;
}
    
#passwrap::after
{
    content: "";
    background-color: #FF008B;
    width: 23.28vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0.85vw;
    height: 0.1vh;
    display: block;
}

#userwrapW::before
{
    content: "Username:";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #FF008B;
    width: 3.56vw;
    height: 1vh;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.65vh;
    left: 1vw;
}
    
#userwrapW::after
{
    content: "";
    background-color: #FF008B;
    width: 38.33vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0.85vw;
    height: 0.1vh;
    display: block;
}
    
#passwrapW::before
{
    content: "Password:";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #FF008B;
    width: 3.56vw;
    height: 1vh;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.65vh;
    left: 1vw;
}
    
#passwrapW::after
{
    content: "";
    background-color: #FF008B;
    width: 38.33vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0.85vw;
    height: 0.1vh;
    display: block;
}

#reenterwrapW::before
{
    content: "Re-enter Password:";
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #FF008B;
    width: auto;
    height: 1vh;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.65vh;
    left: 1vw;
}
    
#reenterwrapW::after
{
    content: "";
    background-color: #FF008B;
    width: 38.33vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0.85vw;
    height: 0.1vh;
    display: block;
}

#loginform button
{
    color: #FF008B;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 11vw;
    height: 2.5em;
    border: 1px solid #FF008B;
    position: relative;
    top: 4em;
    left: 1.2vw;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-out, background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#loginform button:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF008B;
}

#createform button
{
    color: #FF008B;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 93%;
    height: 2.5em;
    border: 1px solid #FF008B;
    margin-top: 1.2vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 4em;
    left: 1.2vw;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-out, background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#createform button:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF008B;
}

p
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    position: relative;
    top: 25vh;
}
```

Comment: I tested the code in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/john-zhuangzhuang-li/pen/dyKRpLL), seems to me that it would reproduce the issue in Chrome but Firefox is fine somehow. Not sure what is the cause though.

Comment: I made the same login page but just used absolute positioning instead of css grid. This achieved the desired result, but I am still not sure why css grid did this and how to disable it. Side note: I did try to use flexbox but it also had the weird highlight on first flex element like css grid was doing???!!! I'm really confused but the page is fine using absolute positioning so I'm good.

Comment: I'm still curious about what could possibly be the cause behind this, but anyways, glad to know that you've found a workaround!